# Espresso checkbox is checked

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am new to Espresso and I have this problem:
How can I check if some checkBox is checked?
I create a matcher from checkbox and I click on it by espresso.

I read some tutorial about use getInstrumentation() but I only can use InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation() and it doesnt work.

In general, how can I create real widget such as Button, CheckBox etc. from Matcher object?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After click you can check that checkbox is checked with such expression:

```
onView(withId(R.id.checkbox)).check(matches(isChecked()));
```

Comment: What if it's a menu, they're also checkable

Comment: If unresolved, remember to import: `import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isChecked;`